# How to check if a React element will render anything

Tags: reactjs, react-fragment

Say I'm making a wrapper component which should only render itself if some child nodes are passed in:

```
const Wrapper = ({children}) => {
  if (!children) return null
  return <div>{children}</div>
}
```

The problem is that `children` could be a `Fragment` containing null, or an array of nulls. Or a fragment containing a fragment containing...

```
<Wrapper>hey</Wrapper> // renders <div>hey</div> 
<Wrapper>{null}</Wrapper> // renders nothing 
<Wrapper>{[null]}</Wrapper> // renders <div/> 
<Wrapper><React.Fragment>{null}</React.Fragment></Wrapper> // renders <div/>
```

Is there a canonical way to check for all these conditions?

Comment: Can you describe a scenario in a bit detail?

Comment: You add a div id, through which you can check if the component with id has rendered or not

Comment: you have to do more checks on `children` like if it's an array, and render accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is what you're looking for :

```
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';

const Wrapper = ({children}) => {
  const markup = ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(children);
  if (!markup.trim()) return null;

  return <div>{children}</div>
}
```

Comment: This could work, thanks. I wonder if there are implications of loading `react-dom/server` on the client side.

Comment: From the react docs, `ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup` can be used in both the server and browser. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#overview

Comment: It looked promising, but this will cause any portals in `children` to be rendered

Answer (score 1):

No need to check. They simply [don't render](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#booleans-null-and-undefined-are-ignored).

> false, null, undefined, and true are valid children. They simply don’t render. These JSX expressions will all render to the same thing:

```
<div />

<div></div>

<div>{false}</div>

<div>{null}</div>

<div>{undefined}</div>

<div>{true}</div>
```

Comment: The children don't render but it's the wrapper I care about (see updated question with examples).